# Display template javascript array

Tags: 2013, display-template

Have an item display template in SharePoint 2013. The returned property has multiple entries and I'm trying to format them with a pipe between them.Here is the code that I put in the html file.

```
function makePretty(prop){
  var tags = prop.split("\n");
  for(var i = 0;i<tags.length;i++){
    var str=tags[i];
    ...
```

For some reason when the html file is uploaded and processed into js it adds quotes to the str assignment.

```
var str="tags[i];"
```

Otherwise it all works, I just end up with output literally like this.

```
tags[i]; | tags[i]; | tags[i];
```

When I expected something like this

```
My tag1 | Tag2 | Value of tag 3
```

Any idea what is going on? How do I put that kind of function into a display template and tell SP to leave it alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the only or correct answer, but we took the same code outside of a function and it works just fine. So

```
var tags = prop.split("\n");
  for(var i = 0;i<tags.length;i++){
    var str=tags[i];
   ...
```

Evidently display templates don't want to let functions have ambiguously typed things?